# Rewrite URL returning "cannot use leading .. to exit top directory"

Tags: iis, sitecore, config, url-rewrite-module

My site was working fine until I added a rewrite rule to remove a subfolder from the URL so that what originally was https://example.com/folder/page would just be https://example.com/page. My file really is located at the /folder/page location... I just don't want /folder/ to appear in the URL to the end user. After doing this I got the following error:

> Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory. Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Cannot use a leading ..
>   to exit above the top directory.

My URL Rewrite rules are as follows:

```
<rule name="Remove Folder" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^folder$|^folder/(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="RewriteToFile" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(?!/folder)(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="folder/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Furthermore, this rule is causing every other page except the home page to return a 404 error.

Also, if it matters, this site is running on Sitecore so the folders and files aren't actual folders or files. They are Sitecore items.

Does anyone know what could now be causing me to have errors?

Comment: You could check solution of this thread https://forums.asp.net/t/1019849.aspx

Comment: I checked out your article and it got me thinking, my paths aren't real folders. They are Sitecore items. Does that help? I'm thinking my rewrite rule has something wrong... Possible with the is file and is folder exceptions since nothing is really a file or folder in sitecore.

Comment: Does any content in /Folder/Page/ currently interact with anything (images, javascript, etc) inside /Folder/?   Or does anything in /Folder/Page/ interact with anything inside /Folder/SomeOtherFolder/?   If I were you, i'd scan thru all my content and look for places where ..\ is used.

Comment: @Rich-Lang These are virtual folders but nothing else is under /Folder/ and /Page/ is the end result so nothing is under it either. The files don't actually exist because the site is database driven. I am seeing 404 errors on every page except the home page and the /Folder/Page page. The home page loads as normal and the /Folder/Page is the one getting the ../ error. The message does point me to a line in my .cshtml file that says @Html.Sitecore().Rendering("/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Feature/Twitter Metadata"). That file has not been changed though and I don't really want to touch it.